# Accessing a local SQL server 2014 from within a VM running vista using VS2005 fails

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-vista, sql-server, sql

My laptop is running Win 7 (x64) and is part of a domain. I've installed SQL Server 2014 Dev and VS2012 on it as I want to use the laptop for development.

Since some of my development has to be done with VS2005, which does not run well in Win 7, I installed Oracle VirtualBox with Vista business 32 bit as the OS. I installed VS2005 in the VM.  I want to use the SQL server I have installed on the host as my backend for development.

When I tried to connect to the SQL server from with in the VS2005 IDE however, I get a message saying the domain is not trusted so windows authentication cannot be used. I've tried change the authentication to use SQL server authentication, but now I'm getting a 'login failed' message. I even tried setting the password for sa and that failed too.

I tried change the login for both the SQL server service and the SQL browser service to a local account, but it didn't work either. I made sure TCP/IP, shared memory, and Named Pipes were all enabled.

Honestly, I'm at my wits end. As far as this topic goes, I didn't have much to begin with. Please help.

Thanks.

Marshall

Answer (score -1):

If it was me, and I had to either sort through the many and varied  issues of fooling a virtual SQL server image which is running on and virtual networking via virtualbox into thinking that its own host laptop was the recipient of outside connectivity rather than the supplier while also running a tunneling virtualLAN connection between the Host and the VM server without letting either one explicitly know and keeping tabs on a really fascinatingly twisted fabrication of address tree this incredibly complex Fib believed by both machines (real and code real) ......OR instead I could throw a quick copy of Vista and dual boot it onto the laptop. Well i might still build the virtual server just to see if I could, but first Id dual boot Vista and 7 on the laptop to get some work done.

Comment: The SQL Server runs in the Win 7 host which also hosts the VM running Vista and VB2005. There is just the one VM. I can see the SQL Server on the host environment from the VM. I just can connect to any of its databases  from there.